# How to view total time taken by Windows services in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 Home Premium installed on my Dell laptop. Recently I have started observing that the wireless icon is taking a long time to appear in the taskbar. I came to know that it could be due to some Windows service that might be taking a long time to finish executing. I am not able to find a way to know how long each service takes to executing so that I can disable the service if I do not find it useful.

I have gone through a a similar thread in this forum, and it listed a few free utilities, but I couldn't find the one that would tell me the time taken by each Windows service.

Could someone please point me to any good utility or any other technique to find the time taken by each Windows service?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean that you want to figure out which programs are taking the most time during the startup process.

A very useful piece of software that serves this purpose is [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/). It monitors your boot process and analyzes how long each service takes to start. It then allows you to delay them or completely remove them from the startup list. It can provide recommendations on what you should do with each one.

[image: Soluto screenshot]